# Range of the generator of a one parameter semigroup of operators?

Tags: functional-analysis

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille%E2%80%93Yosida_theorem)

> If $X$ is a Banach space, a one-parameter semigroup of operators on $X$ is a family of operators indexed on the non-negative real numbers $\{T(t)\} t ∈ [0, ∞)$ such that
>   $$
>     T(0)= I \quad
>     T(s+t)= T(s) \circ T(t), \quad \forall t,s \geq 0.
> $$
>   The infinitesimal generator of a one-parameter semigroup $T$ is **an operator $A$ defined on a possibly proper subspace of $X$** as follows:
>
> - The domain of $A$ is the set of $x ∈ X$ such that $$
>            h^{-1}\bigg(T(h) x - x\bigg)  $$ has a limit as $h$ approaches $0$ from the right.
> - The value of $A x$ is the value of the above limit. In other words $A x$ is the right-derivative at 0 of the function $$
>            t \mapsto T(t)x.  $$

I was wondering if the generator $A$ of a one-parameter semigroup of operators on $X$ is an operator on its domain $D(A)$ in the sense that $A(D(A)) \subseteq  D(A)$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You should consider some examples to convince yourself that this very rarely happens.

Comment: @Martin: Generally, when one mapping is said to be an operator on a subspace of a vector space or a TVS, does it mean that the mapping's range is also in the subspace, or not necessarily?

Comment: No, not at all. In the context of semigroups $A$ is typically an [unbounded operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) $A \colon D(A) \subseteq X \to X$. No further requirement on the range than $A(D(A)) \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $A(D(A)) \subseteq D(A)$ rarely happens.

One of the simplest examples of a semi-group is the translation semigroup on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ given by $T_tf(x) = f(x+t)$ for which one has $$D(A) = \{f \in C_0(\mathbb R) \mid f \text{ is differentiable and } f' \in C_0(\mathbb R)\}$$
and $Af = f'$. Clearly, $A$ doesn't map $D(A)$ into itself.

There are lots of good examples of semigroups with explicit discussion of their infinitesimal generators in the first two chapters of the very readable and detailed [Short course on Operator Semigroups](http://books.google.com/books?id=EKlppf5Nm08C) by Engel and Nagel.